# PDF con contenido de un div en c#

Tags: c#, pdf

Deseo generar un pdf con el contenido de un div. Mi div se llena de forma dinámica, se generan 21 códigos en una sola hoja pero al querer generar más códigos no me genere una segunda hoja.

Les paso un fragmento de mi código.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function genPDF() {
            var pdf = new jsPDF('PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f');
            pdf.addHTML($('#areaImprimir'),
                5,
                5,
                function () {
                    pdf.save('div.pdf');
                });
        }
    </script>



 <div id="areaImprimir" class="well" style="height: 3000px;">
                    <div id="PrintQRStudents" runat="server"></div>
                    <div id="PrintQRRespuestas" runat="server"></div>
                    <div id="PrintQRPuntos" runat="server"></div>
                </div>
```

el div `PrintQRStudents`, `PrintQRRespuestas`, `PrintQRPuntos` son los que se llenan dinámicamente.

Comment: ¿El `height` debe ser de ese tamaño? es posible que se genere la siguiente hoja porque detecta mas contenido a generar *Ejemplo: un espacio, salto de línea*. Use el code snippet-[mira aquí cómo usarlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/430/78) para crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saludos